# Ubuntu Core image for IoT2020

Tags: sd-card, ubuntu-core, disk-image

I want to install ubuntu core on a IoT2020 device (by Siemens) [1].

I couldn't find any Ubuntu Core images or Gadget Snaps for this device, but after a quick web search it seems I can create my own image using `ubuntu-device-flash`.

I'm not sure what options I should be choosing for the IoT2020 device though. I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction?

Related: Is there a place I can request or recommend adding this device to their list of pre-built images?

EDIT: If a existing Ubuntu Core image and gadget snap will work with this device, that would be even better. I just don't know which.

EDIT: I've now also posted a question on Siemens support forums regarding this [2], as well as a github issue on their meta-iot2000 repo [3]

[1] https://uk.rs-online.com/web/generalDisplay.html?id=siemens-simatic-iot2020

[2] https://support.industry.siemens.com/tf/ww/en/posts/creating-a-ubuntu-snappy-core-image/201042/?page=0&pageSize=10#post800662

[3] https://github.com/siemens/meta-iot2000/issues/101

Answer (score 1):

That looks like an X86 device, so you might find the [Intel NUC](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/iot/intel-nuc) images might work there.

Comment: Thx will give that a go. If it fails I'll log a question on snapcraft forums as suggested. ;)

Comment: The image didn't seem to work. In my screen session I just go to the "firmware shell" and it didn't seem to recognise the sd card at all. I've updated my post with links to various other places where I'm trying to get more info.